# How to cast one object into another

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-xml-mapping

I am a beginner in Java and have below 2 Beans/POJOS in my existing company application:

**User**

```
public class User {

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

}
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {


public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

I want to cast `User` to `Employee` because in the application I would be receiving the `User` object in the one of the methods which is used for persisting into the `database` using `hibernate3` xml mapping method. `HIbernate` mapping exists for the `Employee` object and not for `User`. Hence I tried the conversion using the below concept that everything in java is an object but still it is giving the RuntimeException of `ClassCastException` :

```
User u = new User(12,"johnson","pam",new Date());
Object o = u;
Employee e=(Employee)o;
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem? There is no option to change the existing class hierarchies or include any additional inheritance structure.

Comment: you cant cast one object to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast objects at all in Java. You can cast a reference, to a type implemented by the referenced object.

What you can do is *convert* from one object to a new object. If you cannot modify the classes, you can write an external converter. For example:

```
public class EmployeeFactory {
    public static Employee toEmployee( User user ) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setUserId( user.getUserId() );
        emp.setUserName( user.getUserName());
        return emp;
    }
}
```

Comment: dont you think there is a simple way to map? BTW great answer, simple :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast `user` object to an `employee` object as they don't have any relation. You should have some `Mapper` class which will map a `User` object to `Employee` Object.

```
class UserToEmployee{
   public Employee map(User user){
       Employee e = new Employee();
       e.setUserId(user.getUserId());
       // so on set all the required properties
      return e;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
User u = new User(12,"johnson","pam",new Date());
UserToEmployee mapper = new UserToEmployee();
Employee e = mapper.map(u)
```

Comment: isn't there a better way?? BTW i like your way.

Comment: There can be so many ways to do the job. But I used this way in my project many times as it gives an opportunity to inject UserToEmployee object using DI.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Employee` and `User` is completely two different object, so you cannot cast like your case

A simple example

**User**

```
public class User {

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

**Employee**

```
public class Employee extends User {
    //constructor
}
```

Then you can do this

```
Employee e = new Employee();
Object o = e;
User = (Employee) o;
```

Of course, In this case, you **cannot** do the opposite way: cast `User` to `Employee`

Hope this little example help you understand clearly about the case.

Answer (score 0):

In java, an easy way to think about casting objects is: "Am I lying?"
Ie if I cast the User to Employee, I'm saying the User is an Employee. Am I lying? If so, the cast will work. If not, then it wont. Now, according to your logic, you want all Employees to be Users. To establish an "is-a" relationship, you can use the word "extends"

```
class User{
//Your things
}
class Employee extends User{
//More employee-specific things
}
```

Now if you do

```
User john=new User(//args);
```

You can do

```
if(john instanceof Employee){//Make sure john is an employee
Employee johnEmployee=(Employee)john
}
```

All casting is is relabeling an object. But you can't lie about anything that isn't established when the object is made.